# Is it safe to give this info out if I didn't receive an ACH transfer to my account

Tags: united-states, banking, scams, money-transfer, online-banking

I won on an online casino and it's been longer than normal. When I contacted the casino they said they had processed it 7 days ago and if it hasn't hit my account they need the following information so they can send it to their payment dept. webpage/bank URL, name, surname and bank account number, together with all the transactions

Comment: I fail to see any reason for them to ask for the bank’s URL or any transactions on your account. Are you sure that “online casino” is real?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not safe. If they're legitimate they would already have all that information.

Comment: They have all that information.... mixed in with a million other transfers.  OP needs to provide enough for them to search their database.  Probably name, routing number (banks aren't identified by URL) and the last four digits of account number will suffice.

Comment: @BenVoigt if they were legit they'd find it just by the user key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you are really talking to the same company that was supposed to send you the money, they already know your name and account number. You must have given them this information for them to initiate the ACH transaction to begin with. They might ask you to tell them again so they can find the transaction. Or they might ask you to tell them again so they can verify that what they have is correct. If a deposit didn't show up in your account, an obvious possibility is that they have your account number wrong.

If you called them, make sure you have the correct phone number so you know you're talking to the right company. But if you copied a phone number wrong, the chance that this wrong number would turn out to be a scammer is tiny.

If they called you, then I'd seriously consider that it might be a scammer pretending to be the casino. I get scam emails all the time that claim to be from some big bank or from Amazon or some such. Usually the from address on the email is a dead giveaway, but some scammers are smart enough to fake the from address. My general practice is, if someone calls me claiming to be from my bank or some other company I do business with, make them tell me something about my account. At least you tell me my account number or my address or something. The bank should have this information readily available. A scammer who is calling random numbers would not. (A very skillful scammer might have hacked my account, but if he could do that he can probably steal my money without calling me.)

Comment: *But if you copied a phone number wrong, the chance that this wrong number would turn out to be a scammer is tiny* more then once when I by accident dialed 1-800-XXX instead of 1-866-XXX, or dialed 3 instead of 8 in some cases I'd reach scammers specifically preying on such inattentive callers. One time I caught myself half-way through giving my credit card number - because I was calling a credit card company and misdialed one digit.

Comment: @littleadv Fair enough. A few years ago there was a scammer who created a bunch of web sites that were deliberately one letter different from web sites of big companies. Like "amazin.com", that sort of thing. His plan was apparently that users who mistyped the URL would get one of his sites. Then he created web sites that looked like the real site, asked for an ID and password, and whatever you typed, saved it and then gave a message saying the site was down. So he collected a bunch of IDs and passwords.

Comment: Also reminds me: I used to live in a town where all the phone numbers started 372, but then they ran out of numbers so newer numbers got 376. The police department got a 376 number that had the same last four digits as my 372 number. So I got a lot of wrong number calls intended for the police department. It occurred to me that a funny funny prank would be to tell someone, "Yes ma'am, a squad car is on its way", then the next day read in the paper how someone was brutally murdered and the police never showed up. I could laugh and laugh. Oh, wait ...